# python overloading operators

Tags: python, operator-overloading, string-length

I need to implement a DNA class which has attribute a sequence which consists of a string of characters from the alphabet ('A,C,G,T') and I need to overload some operators like less than, greater than, etc..

here is my code:

```
class DNA:
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.seq = sequence

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.seq < other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return(self.seq <= other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return(self.seq > other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return(len(self.seq) >= len(other))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (len(self.seq) == len(other))

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not(self.__eq__(self, other))
```

---

```
dna_1=DNA('ACCGT')
dna_2=DNA('AGT')
print(dna_1 > dna_2)
```

**Problem:**

when I `print(dna_1>dna_2)` it returns `False` instead of `True`... Why?

Comment: Some of your expressions use `len`, others don't. Is this on purpose?

Comment: the len shouldnt be used..i should have removed it sorry

Comment: The comparison of string is according to alphabet. G is after than C, so return False.

Answer (score 19):

You probably want to compare `seq`s:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.seq < other.seq

etc.
```

Not `self`'s `seq` with `other`, `self`'s `seq` with `other`'s `seq`.

`other` here is another DNA.

If you need to compare lengths:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return len(self.seq) < len(other.seq)

etc.
```

Comment: and looking at `__ge__`, `__ne__` and `__eq__`, I think OP wants to compare the `len` of `seq`

Comment: the purpose of __ge__,__ne__,ect are used to compare the length of dna_1 and dna_2

Comment: Didn't you just post that `len` should be removed?

Comment: Anyway, you decide whether you need `len` or not, just look at `seq` on both sides of the comparison.

Comment: when i do use len,it gives an error message..so i got rid of it!and when i print(dna_1>dna_2),it returns the incorrect answer..this is confusing

Comment: You get an error because you use `len` on `other`. Use `len(other.seq)`.

Comment: yes it now works with this def __lt__(self, other):
                               return len(self.seq) < len(other.seq)
but can you explain len(other.seq) please?why is other attached to the first dna?

i have another problem when overloading 'not equal to'(__ne__)..is this the way to write it?
 def __ne__(self,other):
        return not(self.__eq__)

Comment: `self` is attached to the first dna, `other` to the other one.

Comment: why did we not write len(self.seq) < len(other) ?

Comment: We want to compare the `seq` attributes of `self` and `other`, not the `seq` attribute of `self` with the entire `other` itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare with less-than, `__lt__(other)` is called with with a DNA object.
When you call `__init__`, `self.seq` is set to a string (`str`).
So, you are comparing a `str` < `DNA` object.

Magic method are magic, not clairvoyant.  They won't know what you intend the comparison to be, so it will use what it will use a default (probably the output of `repr()`, I didn't check).

You need to specify your design what makes one DNA equal to another.  Your code implies that the sequence length determines equality.  So different sequences can be computed as being equal.  Your equality method therefore implies that a sequence is less than another when it is shorter.  So your method might be better written by comparing the lengths of the sequences rather the `str` to `DNA` object.