# Overriding <= and >= for Python Class

Tags: python

I have following class:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self, key: str):
        self.key = key
        self.value = ''.join(sorted(key))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.value < other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.value > other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        val = other.value
        if self.value == val:
            return True
        return False
```

> and < works. But when I try <= I get following error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Word' and 'Word'
```

How to override <= for python class?

Comment: You might want to use the decorator [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `__ge__` & `__le__`

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self, key: str):
        self.key = key
        self.value = ''.join(sorted(key))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.value < other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.value > other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.value <= other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.value >= other.value:
            return True
        return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        val = other.value
        if self.value == val:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `def __le__(self, other)` (lesser-equal) and `def __ge__(self, other)` (greater equal) as well.

Beside that you should check if your given `other` actually is a `Word` instance, else you might crash because no `other.value` can be accessed:

```
w = Word("hello")
print( w > 1234 )  # crash:  AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Source / Documentation of all of them: [`object.__le__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__)

See

- [python overloading operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461574/python-overloading-operators)

---

Potential fix for comparison:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Word):
        if self.value < other.value:
            return True
    else:
        # return True or False if it makes sense - else use better exception
        raise ValueError(f"Cannot compare Word vs. {type(other)}")
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another special method for this:

```
 def __le__(self, other):
    if self.value <= other.value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```